# Can't connect to Postgresql with specific external IP

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I can connect to my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20LTS VM instant that has PostgreSQL 14 installed without issue, but I'm trying to make it more secure with only specific IPs that can connect to the database.

I heard the way to do this is to modify the `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` file.

When I have this line, I can connect to my database without issue.

`listen_addresses='0.0.0.0'`

However, if I modify this line with:

`listen_addresses='123.123.123.123'`

I get this DataGrip error message: [08001] Connection to 111.111.111.111:12345 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

111.111.111.111:12345 is my (fake) VM's IP and port that I already set up.

123.123.123.123 is my (fake) computer's external IP that I get from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+ip) or [here](https://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Any suggestions? Is there a log I can search from that will give me a better understanding of what is going on?

Also to note, with `listen_addresses='0.0.0.0'`, running `ss -ptl` gives an output of

```
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q           Local Address:Port             Peer Address:Port     Process     
LISTEN     0          4096             127.0.0.53%lo:domain                0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          128                    0.0.0.0:ssh                   0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          244                    0.0.0.0:12345                 0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          128                       [::]:ssh                      [::]:*
```

with `listen_addresses='123.123.123.123'`, running `ss -ptl` gives an output of

```
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q           Local Address:Port             Peer Address:Port     Process     
LISTEN     0          4096             127.0.0.53%lo:domain                0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          128                    0.0.0.0:ssh                   0.0.0.0:*                    
LISTEN     0          128                       [::]:ssh                      [::]:*
```

Documentation that I used so far:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: listen_addresses is used to configure the server to listen on specific IP4 or IPv6 interfaces, this parameter is not for restricting which client IPs can connect to your server.

Comment: In order to control, which IP or IP ranges can connect to your PG db server, you must configure client entries in the `pg_hba.conf` file, see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: After [doing more research](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220959), it looks like I need to focus on the firewall portion since pg_hba.conf and listen_addresses are only a small facet of how to secure your online database. It would still be nice to figure out how to make listen_addresses work with a VPS.

Comment: Of course protecting your DB server by placing it behind a firewall and allowing only certain IP or ranges is the usual and better way. But your initial ask was to limit to certain IP ranges to connect to your database, and for that you should do it via the .conf file, not the listen_addresses parameter.

Comment: So what's the point of listen_addresses if anything other than * or 0.0.0.0 doesn't work? I'm trying to make this part of the many security measures in place to work, not just ignore it entirely.

Comment: Other things will work, but only make sense if your server answers to multiple IP addresses because it has (for example) multiple network cards.  That is a pretty rare situation IME for a database server.